# RGB values from getImageData are undefined

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getimagedata

I want to click on an image and get the RGB values for that pixel.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="kartina" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<form>
<input type="text" id="textField" size="80">
</form>

</body>
<script>
var canvas=document.getElementById("kartina");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var textField=document.getElementById("textField");
canvas.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    var x=event.pageX;
    var y=event.pageY;
    var p=ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
    textField.value="x: "+x+", y: "+y+", R: "+p[0]+", G: "+p[1]+", B: "+p[2];
});


var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
};
img.src="/myApp/pic.jpg";


</script>
</html>
```

When I click on the image, the text box is correctly populated with the coordinates, but all the RGB values are "undefined", e.g.:

```
x: 157, y: 89, R: undefined, G: undefined, B: undefined
```

How can I get the correct RGB values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData) returns an [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object, whose `data` property is the array containing the actual RGB values.

Basically, you're missing a `.data`:

```
var p = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data;
```

Comment: Upvote. Yep...And also mentioning that if the canvas is not on the top-left of the document then you must also adjust the x,y mouse coordinates by the offset of the canvas element.

Answer (score 4):

You need to access the data property of the object returned by getImageData.

```
 var p=ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
 textField.value="x: "+x+", y: "+y+", R: "+p.data[0]+", G: "+p.data[1]+", B: "+p.data[2];
```

Comment: Correct, although John Flatness posted the same correct answer a few minutes before you.

Comment: I just noticed that. Must of happened while I was typing. Should I delete my answer? Or keep it since it's a tad different? (He grabs the data property directly from getImageData eschewing the other properties)

Comment: IMHO, it's an honest mistake, just keep it as is. :-)